# Failed to run java in remote command line with external jar file

Tags: java, javac

I want to run my Java code in remote server with external jar file. I referred to [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-artifacts.html) and run IntelliJ IDE to generate a jar file of my whole project. Now I can run the following code in local terminal successfully.

```
javac -cp /Users/natsuapo/out/artifacts/main_jar/main.jar: new_server_try.java
java -cp /Users/natsuapo/out/artifacts/main_jar/main.jar: new_server_try
```

The code will run successfully. However, when I try the same thing in server. The compile process can be finished without any errors or warnings.

```
javac -cp /Users/natsuapo/out/artifacts/main_jar/main.jar: new_server_try.java
```

I have checked that the class file `new_server_try.class` is generated in the directory.

However the second step will return error as `Could not find or load main class new_server_try` and I am not sure why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the second command try giving the full package name .. like shown below

```
java -cp "/Users/natsuapo/out/artifacts/main_jar/main.jar:lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

also with operating system the command differs, check below

Windows

```
java -cp "Test.jar;lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

Unix

```
java -cp "Test.jar:lib/*" my.package.MainClass
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it and it didn't work and this time it even didn't work in my local environment.

Comment: can you print your command here what you tried .. and what is your OS ?

Comment: is the compile working ? or neither of them worked ?

Comment: I think the compile works both in local and server as I can find `new_server_try.class` in the same directory.

Comment: ok. so the below compile command is running
javac -cp "/Users/natsuapo/Documents/code/PFlowLibFull/out/artifacts/m‌​ain_jar/main.jar" new_server_try.java

Comment: The run command you have to run in the directory where the class file is getting created

Comment: I solve the problem by using `java -cp ".:/Users/natsuapo/Documents/code/PFlowLibFull/out/artifacts/m‌​ain_jar/main.jar" new_server_try`